# Create a re-usable macro to close the Active sheet in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a single macro in excel that I can reuse on any sheets to close the sheet and direct the user back to the "Home" sheet.

I was thinking of something like this? but I get an error at Line 3.

```
    Sub CloseCurrentTab()

    ' CloseCurrentTab Macro

    Dim strCurrentSheet As String
    strCurrentSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets("strCurrentSheet").Visible = False
    Sheets("Home").Activate

    End Sub
```

Comment: There is no concept of "closing" a tab/worksheet in a workbook. you can just activate the "Home" tab directly. `Sheets("Home").Activate`

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your question that you want to create a kind of navigation that hides all but the active sheet.

If this is what you're looking for, you'll need something like the following code:

In a Module:

```
Global Const cStrHomeSheet As String = "Home"

Public Sub subGotoSheet(strSheetName As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim wsActive As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsActive = ActiveSheet

    Sheets(strSheetName).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets(strSheetName).Activate

    wsActive.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Cannot find worksheet " & strSheetName
End Sub

Public Sub subGotoHomeSheet()
    subGotoSheet cStrHomeSheet
End Sub

Public Sub subGotoSheetFromCaller()
    subGotoSheet Application.Caller
End Sub

Public Sub subHideAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False

    Sheets(cStrHomeSheet).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets(cStrHomeSheet).Activate
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Name  cStrHomeSheet Then _
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Public Sub subShowAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True

    For Each ws In Sheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

In addition, place the following code in the `ThisModule` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    subHideAll
End Sub
```

**Explanation & usage:**

The code in the `ThisWorkbook` module will hide all but the home worksheet up loading the workbook. (To hide the fact that you're switching worksheets, it also hide the worksheet tab bar at the bottom left of the window).

By calling a `subGotoSheet "DestinationSheet"` you can now "activate", i.e. unhide the target sheet - the old sheet will be hidden. To make your life a bit easier, you can also call `subGotoHomeSheet` - and even more important, use `subGotoSheetFromCaller`. This one is really neat if you combine it with buttons (or any shapes for that matter): if you insert a button or shape into a worksheet, assign this macro to it. You now only need to name the item (using the name box left of the formula field) according to your target sheet - and the button will automatically get you to desired sheet!

Last but not least, I assume you'll also need a "developer mode" in which you'll see and edit all sheets. To do this, run `subShowAll`, to go back, run `subHideAll`. I'd recommend you to assign shortcut keys to both macros, so you can quickly switch between developer and user mode.

Answer (score 0):

To get it to *compile* change line 3 to:

```
Sheets(strCurrentSheet).Visible = False
```

However this just Hides the sheet; it does not remove it. To delete it (permanently) use:

```
Sheets(strCurrentSheet).Delete
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have used the term "Hide" in my question, this worked.